# vagrant up : No package matching 'server.packages' is available (generated by phansible)

Tags: php, windows, vagrant, ansible, lampp

- I used http://phansible.com/ to generate https://file.io/v3TnEr
- when run vagrant up it gives "No package matching 'server.packages' is available" (log : https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8954010)
- non of packages I've selected has been installed.

I am using windows and hosts file has been updated.
Anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

generated file: /ansible/roles/server/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: Install Extra Packages
  sudo: yes
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=latest
  with_items: server.packages
  when: server.packages is defined
```

should have to be

```
- name: Install Extra Packages
  sudo: yes
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=latest
  with_items: "{{ server.packages }}"
  when: server.packages is defined
```

same way you might have to fix /ansible/roles/php/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: Install PHP Packages
  sudo: yes
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=latest
  with_items: "{{ php.packages }}"
  when: php.packages is defined
```

Other than that /ansible/vars/all.yml

```
php:
    install: '1'
    ppa: php
    packages: [php5-cli, php5-intl, php5-mcrypt, php5-curl, php5-mysql]
```

instead `ppa: php5-5.6`